# FWTools Python ImportError: DLL load failed:parameter is incorrect

Tags: python, gdal, fwtools

[image]

Please, can anyone help me solve this issue? Please find the attached snapshot 
for your reference. I am working on a Windows 7 Professional, Service Pack 1, 32-bit laptop.

Comment: From the [GDAL Wiki](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries): *Important note: the FWTools binaries are not currently updated...* The GDAL/OGR version in FWTools is 1.7 from 2010. Try the [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) or [GIS Internals](http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/) GDAL binaries instead.

Comment: @Erica I don't think it is the same problem, the solution given by user 30184 is already done by the asker. I recommend switching to OSGEO4W too.

Comment: Is ascii_folder a file or a folder? The python script might expect full filenames here.

Comment: ascii_folder is a folder and inside there are ascii file which was obtained after converting raw TRMM HDF datas. Now i need to rotate and clip using pythonscript rotate_clip.py but i can not do due to above error. Please somebody help me and provide step bty step procedure